# auto image slider in js and css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was just wanting a code review on this image slider I made. I don't have anyone else to give me their opinion on the code I write outside of work, so I'm asking here.
okay so i had made an image slider and now i want to give an automatic option to it too. have any one any idea? feel free to tell me your answers.

thank you...

```js
let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slider__slide");
let navlinks = document.getElementsByClassName("slider__navlink");
let currentSlide = 0;

document.getElementById("nav-button--next").addEventListener("click", () => {
    changeSlide(currentSlide + 1)
});
document.getElementById("nav-button--prev").addEventListener("click", () => {
    changeSlide(currentSlide - 1)
});

function changeSlide(moveTo) {
    if (moveTo >= slides.length) {moveTo = 0;}
    if (moveTo < 0) {moveTo = slides.length - 1;}
    
    slides[currentSlide].classList.toggle("active");
    navlinks[currentSlide].classList.toggle("active");
    slides[moveTo].classList.toggle("active");
    navlinks[moveTo].classList.toggle("active");
    
    currentSlide = moveTo;
}

document.querySelectorAll('.slider__navlink').forEach((bullet, bulletIndex) => {
    bullet.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (currentSlide !== bulletIndex) {
            changeSlide(bulletIndex);
        }
    })
})
```

```css
body {
      min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.slider {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slider__slides {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 66%;
}

.slider__slide {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;   
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: 3s;
    opacity: 0;
}

.active {
    opacity: 1;
}

.slider__slide img {
    width: 100%;
} 

.slider__nav-button {
    position: absolute;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    background-color: #333;
    opacity: .8;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#nav-button--prev {
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#nav-button--next {
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#nav-button--prev::after,
#nav-button--next::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border: solid white;
    border-width: 0 4px 4px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 40%;
    height: 40%;
}

#nav-button--next::after{
    top: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    transform: translate(25%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}

#nav-button--prev::after {
    top: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    transform: translate(75%, -50%) rotate(135deg);
}

.slider__nav {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 3%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    text-align: center;
}

.slider__navlink {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px #fff solid;
    background-color: #333;
    opacity: 1;
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slider__navlink.active {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px #333 solid;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .slider__nav-button {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
  }
  .slider__navlink {
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="header"></h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slider__slides ">
      <div class="slider__slide active">
         <img src="https://www.jowhareh.com/images/Jowhareh/galleries_8/poster_ded02296-0311-483b-a706-48b55ca65049.jpeg" alt="img1" />
      </div>
      <div class="slider__slide">
        <img src="https://www.jowhareh.com/images/Jowhareh/galleries_8/poster_c4c38355-e392-40e1-9cce-570b54780c8b.jpeg" alt="img2" />
      </div>
      <div class="slider__slide">
        <img src="https://www.jowhareh.com/images/Jowhareh/galleries_8/poster_29b5b00d-d38d-462d-a528-987516e77f64.jpeg" alt="img3" />
      </div>
      <div class="slider__slide">
        <img src="https://www.jowhareh.com/images/Jowhareh/galleries_8/poster_0acca158-34d3-4a9e-bb35-b598ccebbe08.jpeg" alt="img4" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="nav-button--prev" class="slider__nav-button"></div>
    <div id="nav-button--next" class="slider__nav-button"></div>
    <div class="slider__nav">
      <div class="slider__navlink active"></div>
      <div class="slider__navlink"></div>
      <div class="slider__navlink"></div>
      <div class="slider__navlink"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks good to me, but doesn't "auto" slide? I have to press something to get to the next image.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Thank you for reviewing it. Yes, it is not automated yet. do you have any idea to help about it?I tried using setinterval method to make it auto, but my code messed up...

Comment: Adding the automatic feature shouldn't be too difficult, and `setinterval()` is probably useful, but here we only _review working code_, hence the name: "Code Review". It would be more a question for the normal Stack Overflow, however I found [a reasonable simple example](https://codepen.io/rosansubba/pen/BXZVpo) which also detects when the mouse cursor is over the slider. You can copy parts of that code.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Oh that's right and thanks for your example, it will help.

Comment: Oh, the example uses JQuery, whereas you code in plain Javascript, so you cannot copy the code. Sorry for that. But not copying the code directly means more of the code is yours. 

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Oh, your words gave me more confidence to write my code, it's ok, i'll work on a setinterval method again.

Answer (score 1):

#### 1 HTML

##### 1.1 Indents

The indents within your body are incorrect. Always indent correctly to add readability.

##### 1.2 Semantic tags

Use semantic tags always if suited. Semantic tags rais accessibility and also readability.

```html
<div id="nav-button--prev" class="slider__nav-button"></div>
<div id="nav-button--next" class="slider__nav-button"></div>
```

In the above code lines, you have 2 buttons that require a user's input. A `div` as an unspecific container is not acceptable here. It is a control element that the user is supposed to click on. A `button` would have been more appropriate.

```html
<div class="slider__nav">
  <div class="slider__navlink active"></div>
  <div class="slider__navlink"></div>
  <div class="slider__navlink"></div>
  <div class="slider__navlink"></div>
</div>
```

here you have multiple control elements which should be a list. A `menu` as the container containing buttons would have been correct here.

#### 2 Javascript

##### 2.1 `const` vs `let`

You declare only 3 variables from where only 1 is an actual variable.

```
let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slider__slide");
let navlinks = document.getElementsByClassName("slider__navlink");
let currentSlide = 0;
```

In the code you posted, I would not expect the first 2 "variables" to change. As such they are technical constants. 
You should use a `const` wherever suited and mark them by writing them all capitals so you can spot differences between variables and constants.

##### 2.2 `getElementsByClassName` vs `querySelectorAll`

`getElementsByClassName` will return an **HTML Collection Object** while `querySelectorAll` will return a **Node List*. Both are an array-like list with only a few differences. `getElementsByClassName` will be slightly faster within nanoseconds. `querySelectorAll` can select elements with the same rules as CSS and not only classes but also allows the usage of `forEach` as an iteration method.

```js
/* JS:2  */   let navlinks = document.getElementsByClassName("slider__navlink");
/* JS:24 */   document.querySelectorAll('.slider__navlink')
```

If you would have used `document.querySelectorAll` it *JS-line 2* then you could have used that constant later on instead of writing the whole document selector again.

##### 2.3 Modulus Operator

You can use the modulus (`%`) to get the remainder of a division. This can help you in certain cases to shorten calculations such as infinite iterations. You have used:

```js
if (moveTo >= slides.length) {moveTo = 0;}
if (moveTo < 0) {moveTo = slides.length - 1;}
```

You have 2 "slow" if statements while a simple modulus calculation would be shorter and faster such as:

```js
moveTo = (moveTo + slides.length) % slides.length;
```

```js
let moveTo= 0;
const slides = [1, 2, 3, 4];

function changeSlide() {
  moveTo = (moveTo + slides.length) % slides.length;
  console.log(moveTo);
}


/* just to be demostratable */
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(btn => 
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.clear();
    switch (this.id) {
      case 'plus':
        moveTo++;
        break;
      case 'minus':
        moveTo--;
        break;
    }
    changeSlide();
  })                                           
)
```

```html
<button id="plus">+</button>
<button id="minus">-</button>
```